# Doctrine2 change Tablename Format

Tags: php, configuration, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

Im using ZF2 with DoctrineModule and DoctrineORMModule.

**Problem:** I got some Tablenames in my Database that are equal to MYSQL Commands
Doctrine generates Tablenames in SQL Statements without the "`"'s

```
SELECT ... FROM references
```

But I want it to be like this Format

```
SELECT ... FROM `references`
```

to be safe..

**How to Fix it in Doctrine 1** to fix my Problem I had done this:
    https://i.stack.imgur.com/UN5KB.png

(link: http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_0/fr/configuration:naming-convention-attributes:table-name-format)

I do not find any Fix for this Problem in Doctrine2.
Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Doctrine2 there is no automatic identifier quoting. What you could do in this case is directly putting the quotes inside your mappings, like following:

```
@Table(name="`references`")
```

That should do the trick, but won't work with schemas and SQLite in 2.2.